# Chef test kitchen and policyfiles

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen, policyfiles

This is my current situation, I have a single cookbook in an internal git repo. In that cookbook I have to keep several policy files and test them, for that I created a directory called policyfiles inside the cookbook, being something like this:

```
MyCookbook
|--attributes
|--recipes
|--templates
|--spec
|--policyfiles
|   |- a.rb
|   |- b.rb
|--other files.
```

My problem is that I have to test those a.rb and b.rb policyfiles with Kitchen, so I tried using **chef_zero** without any luck reading those policyfiles and then tried **policyfile_zero** as Kitchen provisioner... in this case it can read a policyfile lock file (For example, *a.lock.json*) but only if it is placed in the cookbook root directory and renamed to *Policyfile.lock.json*

This is extremely clunky and not practical, could anyone please provide some insight about how to test policyfiles locally with Kitchen? I can't believe this is the only way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So answering to my own question, discovered doing further random trial and error, it seems to be a problem in the way I was using chef_zero and telling it where the policyfile is.

Previously with policyfile_zero provisioner, the structure of a suite in chef kitchen could be like:

```
suites:
  - name: MySuite
    provisioner:
      policyfile: policyfiles/a.rb
```

Which won't work. However the syntax now for this is:

```
suites:
  - name: MySuite
    provisioner:
      policyfile_path: policyfiles/a.rb
```

This will no only work but auto *chef install* the policyfile, creating a fresh lock file in the policyfile path and apply it without renaming to the provisioned machine.

Comment: Sorry about that, recent versions of Test Kitchen re-added the old name for backwards compat.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. `Reason: (CookbookOmnifetch::NotACookbook) The resource at '/home/myhome/cookbooks/my_cookbook/policyfiles' does not appear to be a valid cookbook. Does it have a metadata.rb?`

Comment: Oops, gota change the path in the Policyfile! `cookbook 'my_cookbook', path: '..'`